# What is the meaning of Built-in functions in GCC?

Tags: function, gcc, built-in

when using gcc we can write a standard c program without including any library , How does gcc using the functions without there libraries , in other words Where are the functions' prototype and bodies ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC is built with a number of standard options. You can observe them when you invoke `gcc -v` on your file, or you can explicitly increase the verbosity of the linker with `gcc -v <file> -Wl, --verbose`.

Note that you can pass the `-nostdlib`, `-nostdinc` option to gcc to remove default C includes and `-nostdinc++` to remove the default C++ includes.

For example, when I invoke with `-v` I can see the following snippet on cygwin,

> COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic'
>   '-march=x86-64'
>        /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/collect2.exe -m i386pep --wrap _Znwm --wrap _Znam --wrap _ZdlPv --wrap _ZdaPv --wrap _ZnwmRKSt9nothrow_t --wrap _ZnamRKSt9nothrow_t --wrap _ZdlPvRKSt9nothrow_t --wrap _ZdaPvRKSt9nothrow_t -Bdynamic --dll-search-prefix=cyg --tsaware /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/../../../../lib/crt0.o
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/crtbegin.o
>   -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/lib/../lib
>   -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/../../../../lib -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/../../.. /tmp/ccIyoOMf.o -lstdc++ -lgcc_s -lgcc -lcygwin -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/crtend.o

The `COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS` variable will be passed to all the sub-processes GCC is driving, but in particular you can see that it will link with the `-lstdc++ -lgcc_s -lgcc -lcygwin -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lgcc_s -lgcc` libraries by default in this example.

Comment: It's `-nostdinc` with a single dash, and I think `-nostdlib` is more relevant here.

Comment: Yes of course, thank you for noticing. Was writing this after `--verbose` so the double dash was still imprinted in my mind.

Answer (score -1):

`libc` is included by default and it contains all the standard input and output functions e.g. `stdio`/`stdlib`.

Answer (score -2):

The linker has some default options which, unless explicitly changed, are linking to some core C stuff.

Comment: where is this core C stuff ? in gcc.exe ?